Cloning profile using custom plugin
I'm creating a custom sf plugin and using that to clone a custom admin profile and copy over ALL its contents(mainly FLS, Object permissions, apex class access etc) to another target profile.
The idea is to use it in a custom plugin so that this can be run after every deployment in our CI/CD pipeline in github actions, since I do not have my target profile in the CICD pipeline(This is intentional).
I have created the sf plugin and the necessary cmds.
I am doing a connection.metadata.read of the source custom profile and then converting the XML to Typescript object and then assigning the necessary details to my target profile and then calling the connection.metadata.update to update my target profile.
The issue I'm facing is that the update fails with error related to tab settings as below:
Error: You can't edit tab settings for AppointmentInvitation, as it's not a valid tab.
This is repeated multiple times for various tabs.
I tried NOT assigning tabVisbilities to my target profile altogether, but it did not work.
How can I achieve cloning in my sf plugin via the metadata.update function? How to know / fetch ONLY the tabs that can be assigned?
Any help in this regard would be appreciated!

I'd assume you have some issues with copying the license or some related configuration. Because if a standard profile has specific Tab visibility you should be able to deploy custom profile with the same tabs

@ytiq, They have the same license.
